# What does "{} \;" mean in the find command?

Tags: command-line, find

Sometimes I see the following command:

```
find . -name  * -exec ls -a {} \;
```

I was asked to execute this.

What does `{} \;` mean here?

Comment: `-name *` is redundant.

Comment: Also check out [explainshell](http://explainshell.com/) for other types of questions like this. [Here's the output for your command.](http://explainshell.com/explain/find?args=.+-name++*+-exec+ls+-a+%7B%7D+%5C%3B).

Comment: `-name *` is worse than redundant. Because the `*` is unquoted, the shell expands it to the list of file names in the current folder, with spaces being incorrectly treated, leading to unexpected results or an error message. As an extra point, `find` has many functions, one of them being to list files; this avoids having to use `-exec`. E.g., you can use `find . -print` or `find . -ls`. Finally, there are two ways to escape the semi-colon: either as you did with the backslash, `\;`, or by quoting: `';'`. Use whichever you feel more comfortable with.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you run `find` with `exec`, `{}` expands to the filename of each file or directory found with `find` (so that `ls` in your example gets every found filename as an argument - note that it calls `ls` or whatever other command you specify once for each file found).

Semicolon `;` ends the command executed by `exec`. It needs to be escaped with `\` so that the shell you run `find` inside does not treat it as its own special character, but rather passes it to `find`.

See [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20130204072017/http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/unix/findcmd.htm) for some more details.

---

Also, `find` provides some optimization with `exec cmd {} +` - when run like that, `find` appends found files to the end of the command rather than invoking it once per file (so that the command is run only once, if possible).

The difference in behavior (if not in efficiency) is easily noticeable if run with `ls`, e.g.

```
find ~ -iname '*.jpg' -exec ls {} \;
# vs
find ~ -iname '*.jpg' -exec ls {} +
```

Assuming you have some `jpg` files (with *short enough paths*), the result is one line per file in first case and standard `ls` behavior of displaying files in columns for the latter.

Comment: I think it would be beneficial for you to contrast `\;` with `+`.

Comment: How does it differ from `find . -name * | ls -a -`?

Comment: @DrH The point is not to let shell do the wildcard expansion but rather pass the wildcard expression to `find`. Also, output of `ls` in this case apparently does not depend on the input - no matter what I use as a filter for `find`, `ls` just displays the working directory contents and that's all. Check for example `find ~ -iname '*.jpg' -exec ls -a {} \;` vs `find ~ -iname '*.jpg' | ls -a`.

Comment: @DrH or even `echo 'foo' | ls -a`.

Comment: @moon.musick, I believe you've missed off the important `-` in your `ls -a -` command when testing what @dr-h queried.

Comment: @DanielLlewellyn Yeah, if that's a normal dash then it yields `ls: cannot access -: No such file or directory` both in `bash` and `zsh` when the `*` is quoted, and the same, but with additional `find: paths must precede expression` error and usage message when `*` is not quoted. Am I really missing something?

Answer (score 33):

From the [manpage for the `find` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/find):

```
-exec command ;
              Execute  command;  true if 0 status is returned.  All following arguments to find are taken to be arguments to
              the command until an argument consisting of `;' is encountered.  The string `{}' is replaced  by  the  current
              file name being processed everywhere it occurs in the arguments to the command, not just in arguments where it
              is alone, as in some versions of find.  Both of these constructions might need to be escaped (with a  `\')  or
              quoted  to  protect them from expansion by the shell.
```

So here's the explanation:

`{}` means "the output of `find`". As in, "whatever `find` found". `find` returns the path of the file you're looking for, right? So `{}` replaces it; it's a placeholder for each file that the `find` command locates (taken from [here](http://kb.iu.edu/data/admm.html)).

The `\;` part is basically telling `find` "okay, I'm done with the command I wanted to execute".

#### Example:

Let's say I'm in a directory full of `.txt` files. I then run:

```
find . -name  '*.txt' -exec cat {} \;
```

The first part, `find . -name  *.txt`, returns a list of the `.txt` files. The second part, `-exec cat {} \;` will execute the `cat` command for every file found by `find`, so `cat file1.txt`, `cat file2.txt`, and so on.

Comment: The part `*.txt` must be quoted as `'*.txt'`. This is because if there are `.txt` files in the current folder, the shell will expand this and you will get incorrect results or an error message. `find -name '*.txt' -exec cat {} \;`

Comment: @Alaa Ali very well explained